# Username Recovery throwing Callback URL validation failed

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Wso2 identity server version : 5.11.0

After changing the admin password , I am getting below error during username recovery.
*Error!
Callback URL validation failed. org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.endpoint.util.client.IdentityRecoveryException: Error while instantiating IdentityProviderMgtServiceStub*

[image]

Error logged in Wso2 identity server wso2carbon.log:

*[2021-09-06 03:29:02,012] [efd866e3-0236-46d7-bcc1-be378dfbcac8]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} - Login failed. Unauthorized login attempt 'admin[-1234]' at [2021-09-06 03:29:02,012+0000]
[2021-09-06 03:29:02,012] [efd866e3-0236-46d7-bcc1-be378dfbcac8]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler} - Illegal access attempt at [2021-09-06 03:29:02,0012] from IP address 127.0.0.1 while trying to authenticate access to service IdentityProviderMgtService*

Can someone please advise.

I changed admin password from WSO2 console, and login is working fine with updated password.
However during username recovery, it throws illegal access attempt in logs.
What am I missing here?

I already updated the new password in cipher-text.properties and user-mgt.xml file too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do config overriding in the ***RecoveryEndpointConfig.properties*** file which located in

***<IS_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/webapps/accountrecoveryendpoint/WEB-INF/classes***

Change the

```
identity.server.service.access.password=admin
```

to the one that you updated in the admin console.